# Ошибка в примерах у Розенталя? О кавычках для прямой речи при наличии "говорит"

Tags: кавычки, прямая-речь

В правилах **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158)** (пункт 1, примечание 2.3) и в  **[ПАС под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)** (§ 136, примечание *б*) **теория** одна и та же: кавычки при наличии вводного слова  ***«говорит»*** **не нужны**.

В то же время Розенталь приводит примеры из текстов, где **кавычки стоят**. В современной практике  встречаются **оба варианта:**  может быть, между ними есть **разница**, но какая?

Вопрос имеет **практическое** значение, хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.

**P S.** Могу предположить, что оформление зависит **от контекста.** При отсутствии кавычек прямая речь уже не считается **самостоятельной** конструкцией, а включается в **авторский** текст (или в реплику лица в **диалоге)**.

Вероятно, для этого недостаточно только слова ***"говорит"***, а нужны **дополнительные** условия. И касается это прежде всего именно **диалогов**, откуда были взяты примеры у **Розенталя**.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

Примеры **у Розенталя:** *Умру, говорит, и слава Богу, **говорит**; не желаю, **говорит**, жить* (Т.); *Я, **говорит**, самого вахмистра жандармерии из пистолета убить хочу* (Верш.);

[Тургенев  Затишье (глава 6)](http://turgenev-lit.ru/turgenev/proza/zatishe-6.htm)

[Петр Вершигора. Люди с чистой совестью, стр. 38](https://sharlib.com/read_183357-38)

Пример **в ПАС**: *Я, **говорит,** хочу закончить институт, профессию получить.*

**Диалог 1**

```
 — Ах! Егор Капитоныч убитый человек. У него жена 
 умерла.
 — Не может быть!
 — В сутки умерла, от холеры. Вы бы не узнали его 
 теперь, просто на себя не похож стал. "Без Матрены 
 Марковны, говорит, жизнь мне в тягость. Умру, 
 говорит, и слава богу, говорит; не желаю, говорит, 
 жить". Да, пропал бедняк.
```

**Диалог 2**

```
— Да он кто же такой, этот детина?
— Да киномеханик. В райцентре. Киношку крутит....Уже 
когда мы вошли у него в доверие, он мне раз 
шепотом признался: "Я, говорит, самого вахмайстера 
жандармерии из пистолета убить хочу!" Глаза блестят 
этаким жертвенным огнем.
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести приемы с  кавычками с этим глаголом? У Розенталя мне найти не удалось.

Comment: Серж, я добавила контекст из книг.

Comment: Я тоже не понял, о каких ошибках в примерах Розенталя идет речь, все примеры у него без кавычек.

Comment: А это редакторы Розенталя выбросили контекст вместе с кавычками)) Но вопрос не только в этом. Надо научиться различать варианты: ставим кавычки или не ставим кавычки. У меня есть версия, но я бы хотела услышать другие.  Здесь очень нужна креативность) в практически важном вопросе.

Comment: В чем ошибка? Пишет, что кавычки не нужны, а примеры приводит из художественных произведений, где кавычки стоят.  Это что, не ошибка?  Кто ошибся-то?  А у Лопатин пример ниоткуда, так что проверить нельзя.

Comment: Мне так и не удалось найти примеры с кавычками у Розенталя. Какое у вас издание? Надо посмотреть в других, старых, его изданиях.

Comment: @Серж, да не у Розенталя. Он взял примеры из художественных текстов, но изменил их: убрал контекст вместе с кавычками. Не видно, что он из диалогов, а тогда все нормально: упрощенное оформление дословного высказывания. (Спасибо за голосование.)

Comment: Тогда все понятно. В первоисточнике предложение с глаголом "говорит" включено в прямую речь. Кавычки нужны. Взятое отдельно такое предложение не заключается в кавычки.

Comment: А почему включено?  Ведь возможен упрощенный вариант (без кавычек + вводное слово).  Недавно была такая тема на форуме, приходилось выбирать. Из-за чего и весь разговор вышел.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Есть ли ошибка** в правилах Розенталя? К самому правилу вопросов нет: **упрощенное оформление** дословного высказывания с помощью вводных слов и без кавычек используется часто.

Но есть неточность **в приведенных примерах,** а именно **свободное** обращение с художественным текстом. Предложения приведены **без контекста и без кавычек**, которые были в авторском варианте. А разве это важно? Ну вот я проверяю и вижу, что кавычки были. И начинаются вопросы.

Дело в том, что в авторском тексте эти предложения включены **в диалог,** а там нужны особые требования. Диалог — это **разговор двух лиц**, при этом в каждой реплике говорящий — это 1-ое лицо, а его собеседник — 2-ое лицо.

Поэтому говорить **о третьих лицах** в 1-ом или 2-ом лице не всегда  возможно, так как в некоторых случаях смысл будет **неправильно** понят. А это уже считается   **стилистической** ошибкой.

2. **Рассмотрим предложение** из диалога 2: *Я, **говорит**, самого вахмайстера жандармерии из пистолета убить хочу!*

**Про кого** здесь говорится? Про киномеханика, но эту фразу без кавычек можно говорить **к говорящему**: будто бы это он собирается вахмайстера жандармерии убить. Читатель поймет, конечно, но стиль получается **некорректный**. Поэтому в авторском тексте использованы **кавычки**.